# O navegador exibe meu código python ao invés de executá-lo

Tags: python

Ao acessar pelo navegador minha página em Python, ela exibe o código e não executa o script.

**Segue meu código:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cabecalho que informa o browser para renderizar como HTML
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
# o conteudo em si
print "<strong>Hello, world!</strong>"
```

Comment: O navegador não interpreta Python. A única linguagem que o navegador interpreta é Javascript. Caso queira trabalhar com CGI, você precisa de um servidor (como Apache ou Nginx) e do módulo Python instalado nele (mod_wsgi ou uWsgi), para que o SERVIDOR gere páginas HTML e envie para o navegador. Dessa forma aí, o navegador só vai lhe mostrar o texto mesmo.

Comment: @inovapixel Como faço para trabalhar na web com Python?

Comment: É como eu disse, você precisa de um servidor rodando o módulo responsável por interpretar Python. Isso se chama CGI (common gateway interface), e pode ser feito com Python, Perl, C/C++, e algumas outras linguagens... Essas linguagens são multi-purpose (multi propósito), elas não são específicas para a Web, então, você começar com elas é mais difícil. Recomendo que se você quer aprender a programar para a Web, comece com Php, pois ele já vem pronto para rodar, basta baixar e instalar programas como o XAMPP, WAMPSERVER, VERTRIGO SERVER e etc... Eles já vem com tudo pronto para programar em Php.

Comment: A maneira mais fácil de iniciar com python na web é utilizando um framework, há dezenas deles, escolha um fullstack popular (Django, TurboGears e Web2py, meu preferido é o django) [Veja uma lista, aqui.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Answer (score 0):

Abra seu terminal e instale o `flask`.

Para instalar o `flask` basta...

```
pip install flask
```

python3 -c "import flask; print(flask.**version**)"

Para executar seu aplicativo Web, diga primeiro ao Flask onde encontrar o aplicativo (o arquivo helly.py no seu caso) com a variável de ambiente FLASK_APP:

```
export FLASK_APP=hello
```

Em seguida, execute-o em modo de desenvolvimento com a variável de ambiente FLASK_ENV:

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

Por último, execute o aplicativo utilizando o comando flask run:

```
flask run
```